# How to do ASP.Net Core Authentication using Active Directory and Database

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity

I am trying to replace an application with an ASP.NET Core upgrade. The existing system uses Forms Authentication. The username and password are checked against an Active Directory and if valid, the user's roles are read from a database table. This set of roles are used to check access against pages.

I am looking at how I do this in ASP.Net Core. Do I need to use Identity? I have looked at different web sites and they all seem to do Identity different ways using a database.

Some code I have found for the database is

```
    services.AddDbContext<AppIdentityDbContext>(options =>
    options.UseSqlServer(Configuration["ConnectionStrings:IdentityConnection"]));

    services.AddIdentity<IdentityUser, IdentityRole>()
              .AddEntityFrameworkStores<AppIdentityDbContext>();
```

and

```
            services.ConfigureApplicationCookie(options =>
            {
                // Cookie settings
                options.Cookie.HttpOnly = true;
                options.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5);

                options.LoginPath = "/Identity/Account/Login";
                options.AccessDeniedPath = "/Identity/Account/AccessDenied";
                options.SlidingExpiration = true;
            });
```

but how does this fit into checking the role against my database? where does it mention my tables and fields in the database? what about authentication against the active directory?

I don't want to use somebody else's database structure because I have my own.

Comment: Have you looked at [SignInManager](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.identity.signinmanager-1?view=aspnetcore-5.0)? and [Configure Windows Authentication in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/windowsauth?view=aspnetcore-5.0&tabs=visual-studio)?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, the forms authentication has been replaced with Cookie authentication in asp.net core.

If you don't want to use identity in asp.net core, I suggest you could try to use Cookie authentication.

In the cookie authentication, you could create an authentication cookie by yourself like this:

```
var claims = new List<Claim>
{
    new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, user.Email),
    new Claim("FullName", user.FullName),
    new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, "Administrator"),
};

var claimsIdentity = new ClaimsIdentity(
    claims, CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);

var authProperties = new AuthenticationProperties
{
    //AllowRefresh = <bool>,
    // Refreshing the authentication session should be allowed.

    //ExpiresUtc = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.AddMinutes(10),
    // The time at which the authentication ticket expires. A 
    // value set here overrides the ExpireTimeSpan option of 
    // CookieAuthenticationOptions set with AddCookie.

    //IsPersistent = true,
    // Whether the authentication session is persisted across 
    // multiple requests. When used with cookies, controls
    // whether the cookie's lifetime is absolute (matching the
    // lifetime of the authentication ticket) or session-based.

    //IssuedUtc = <DateTimeOffset>,
    // The time at which the authentication ticket was issued.

    //RedirectUri = <string>
    // The full path or absolute URI to be used as an http 
    // redirect response value.
};

await HttpContext.SignInAsync(
    CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, 
    new ClaimsPrincipal(claimsIdentity), 
    authProperties);
```

You could add your own logic to work with AD and database inside these codes to generate the authentication cookie.

More details about how to use cookie authentication, you could refer to this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/cookie?view=aspnetcore-5.0).